# while loop does not terminate with sentinel value

Tags: c++

I am a new coder for c++, i am learning it recently thus I may be missing basic elements and understanding. I am creating a c++ file which takes into account various information until -1 sentinel value is input and then it summarizes the information. My while loop does not terminate when I input -1 in student numbers. Can I get some advice and thoughts on the code? Am I missing something ? I am new so any criticism is welcome I just started a month ago. I am theorizing that my while loop may be too big should I put braces or take another approach to the problems, Thanks

```
while (studentnumber != -1)
{

    cout<<"Enter student number:"<<endl;
    cin>> studentnumber;
    numberofstudents ++;


    cout<<"Gender (1=male, 2=female):"<<endl;
    cin>> gender;


    if (gender==1){
        gendermale ++;
    }
    else {
        genderfemale++;
    }

    cout<<"Age:"<<endl;
    cin>> Age;
    average += Age/numberofstudents;


    cout<<"Program of study:"<<endl;
    cin>> prgstudy;

    if (prgstudy=="COEN"){
        prgstudycoen ++;
    }
    else
        prgstudyelec++;

}

cout<<"Statistics:"<<endl;

cout<<"Total number of students is: "<<numberofstudents<<endl;

cout<<"Number of male students is: "<<gendermale<<endl;

cout<<"Number of female students is: "<<genderfemale<<endl;

cout<<"Average age of students is:"<<average<<endl;

cout<<"Number of COEN students:"<<prgstudycoen<<endl;

cout<<"Number of ELEC students:"<<prgstudyelec<<endl;
```

Comment: what the type of `prgstudy` ?

Comment: "I am theorizing that my while loop may be too big" turn this thought into reality and remove everything from the loop that is not related to the problem and solve that first ;) Also read about [mcve]

Comment: There is a lot of unchecked IO in there opening up the possibility of the program packing away an infinite loop's worth of bad readings if the reader makes a typo.

Comment: Unrelated: 1 is male, but you've left open every other number as female. You should probably trap and reject the input if the user specified anything but 1 or 2. For the purposes of this comment we are not taking into account non-binary gender identities.

Comment: there is no problem with while loop being 'too big' (stylistically yes, but not technically). As R Sahu points out, your code is doing exactly what you say, you are just saying the wrong thing

Comment: Ok thanks guys I think I understand however while (true) so i do not understand that much as in what is true, i have not defined the while statement, when do I know it will stop being true. Sorry for basic questions just trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the check for the sentinel value right after you read it, not after it's been processed.

```
while ( true )
{
   cout<<"Enter student number:"<<endl;
   cin>> studentnumber;
   if ( studentnumber == -1 )
   {
      break;
   }

   // Use studentnumber
}
```

You can put the check in the conditional of the `while` by using a helper function to read the input.

```
int readStudentNumber()
{
   int studentnumber;
   cout<<"Enter student number:"<<endl;
   cin>> studentnumber;
   return studentnumber;
}


while ( (studentnumber = readStudentNumber()) != -1 )
{

   // Use studentnumber
}
```